Managing list state across mutliple screens
I am prototyping a mobile app in React Native that should be able to work with lists the following way:
For example on the landing page you have a full list overview with full set of items, on the child screen you should be able to see a specific group of items (let's say only with even id numbers) and going even one screen deeper into stack user should be shown only one item (with specific id).
Now I am fetching all data on the first screen from SQL, save it in a state. When I need to navigate further (React Stack Navigator) I filter state and pass state + setState with filtered items to the next screen, save it into state (same for the next screen). SQL lib is handling saving data to the database just fine on every screen directly but my biggest question is maintaining responsive UI across all screens since one list is a subset of another - for that I am updating parent states inside of children.
Is there a more elegant way/pattern of doing so?

I would recommend to use the right tool for the right job:

Context API


If your application is small and growing, this is great for simple applications or when you need to avoid prop drilling.
Dev tools - Limited
Community - High


Redux


If your application is grows larger. this is best for state predictability and to maintain a single source of truth.
Dev tools - Excellent
Community - very high


MobX State Tree (MST)


this is my personal favorite, its a simple and more reactive approach. Can be used for applications that need easy state updates without much boilerplate. Good tutorial on this here
Dev tools - Good
Community - medium


XState


this is best for applications with complex state logic and transitions. It provides clear state management through state machines.
Dev tools - Good
Community - still growing

Hope this helps :)
